# Change the ticks on x-axis

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to figure out d3.js. While defining the axis, How can I get custom labeling on x-axis. For example, the default labeling I get is:

```
|------|------|------|------|------|------|
20    30     40     50     60     70     80
```

Whereas, I want something like:

```
|------|------|------|------|------|------| ....
20    26      32    38     44     50     56
```

I am currently learning it and working on code (slightly modified) from official examples supplied:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickPadding(7).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickPadding(5).orient("left");
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The default ticks for quantitative scales are multiples of 2, 5 and 10. You appear to want multiples of 6; though unusual, this could make sense depending on the nature of the underlying data. So, while you can use [axis.ticks](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_ticks) to increase or decrease the tick count, it will always return multiples of 2, 5 and 10 — not 6.

If you want multiples of 6, you can use [axis.tickValues](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues) to specify the tick values explicitly. This is typically used in conjunction with [d3.range](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#range). For example:

```
xAxis.tickValues(d3.range(20, 80, 4));
```

If you want to compute the values dynamically, use the x-scale’s domain to retrieve the lowest and highest value. Also keep in mind that the upper bound of the range is exclusive, so in the above example the largest tick value is 76. You can make the upper bound inclusive by making the stop value of the range slightly bigger (e.g., 81).

Comment: Haha! Had figured it out and came here to answer the question myself, but anyways your post was indeed helpful. Thanks! :)

Comment: @mbostock, I have 24 categories in a quantitative scale, but adding .ticks(6) to my xAxis does nothing - all 24 still show. Any ideas?

Comment: [The d3 source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/f59fc64a20d57fe08be9fb6e53ab0022f6f6c732/test/svg/axis-test.js) now says that tickSubdivide is deprecated and does nothing.

Comment: @mbostock. What if my xAxis labels are dates? How do the skips the labels?