# What does it take for .ticks() to work?

Tags: d3.js

.ticks() doesn't seem to be working on my bar chart. Can somebody take a look?

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/9tfD2/1/). I set ticks on the x-axis near the beginning of the object:

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").ticks(3),
```

Comment: Err... Could you expand a bit on what you mean by 'not working' The fiddle looks to have ticks on the x axis.

Comment: I've set `ticks()` to 3 on the xAxis, yet the default (in this case, one tick for each category) is taking precedence. I have read somewhere that d3 still 'guesses', even when you explicitly specify the number of ticks. But still, I would expect that after specifying a number as low as 3, it would choose a number less than 12 (which is the maximum in this case). [Here's the relevant portion of the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks).

Comment: As it says in the doc, no, it doesn't just take the number you specify. You can use the `tickValues()` function to specify tick marks explicitly though.

Comment: `tickValues` doesn't work for me as the categories can change.

Answer (score 17):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to that first post but I think there is a misunderstanding.

The labels on the axis must be a multiple of 2, 5, or 10.  The ticks function can take any number but it will modify that number to make sure the axis is a multiple of 2, 5, or 10.

For example, if the domain is 0-100 and you want 4 ticks (0, 33.33, 66.66, 100) it will round up to 6 to give you "pretty" numbers (0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100).  However, if you set ticks to 3 it will honor that and you'll have 0, 50, and 100.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102118/5354766)'s a post with Mike's explanation of this behavior.

It is still unclear to me why it won't count 0, 25, 50, 75, 100 if you set the ticks to 5 but I thought I'd try to clear up at least some of the confusion.

Answer (score 10):

ticks can take only multiple of 2,5,10 not any number . That is why you might be having problem . Please take a look at this answer for custom ticks.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100314/change-the-ticks-on-x-axis)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I forgot about it. I actually commented on that post back in January, for seemingly the same type of issue: a bar chart with 24 categories, one for each hour. Unfortunately, `.ticks(5)` isn't working for me either.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a *filter* to decide which ticks to display:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickValues(x.domain().filter(function(d, idx) { return idx%2==0 }))
    .orient("bottom");
```

The snipped above comes from [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3212294).

Comment: So strange to end up here using this same technique five years later :)

Answer (score 1):

A css-way to do this is to hide the nth axis elements you do not want. The d3 ticks, to me, is just perpetually annoying.

```
.tick:nth-of-type(6) > text {
    display: none;
  }
  .tick:nth-of-type(7) > text {
    display: none;
  }
  .tick:nth-of-type(8) > text {
    display: none;
  }
```

Comment: I love it! Very simple and clever