# Strange Gridline Behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Dashboard 1: https://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/073f2f9b4b9a0c88211c9c643e47e9a9

Dashboard 2: https://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/c16c1168705ea18b7d8711c15e90f8ec

I would love if someone could explain why the gridlines in the second link on the bottom right-hand graph are of a higher tick interval (or whatever you want to call it) than the ones in the first link. The d3 template is one I made a few weeks ago and it's just something I'm copying and pasting to use with different data sets. However, despite hours of double checking everything, I'm still not sure why it's doing that.

The only thing that's different is the data, but they are of very similar types of data, the domains should be similar. For example, the bottom right hand graph is all positive number for both dashboards. Maybe it's being parsed differently for some strange reason?

Let me know how you did it, whether you brute forced the styling of the gridlines, or if you found the trigger of the problem. That is to say, why it chose to add so many more gridlines on that graph but none of the others.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To regulate the number of `ticks` use ticks(4)

read [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#ticks) this will generate 4 ticks in x axis.

```
var xGridlineNodes = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + (totalHeight - margins.bottom + axisPadding) + ')')
        .call(xGridlinesAxis.tickSize(-graphHeight - axisPadding, 0, 0).tickFormat("").ticks(4));
```

The reason why there are more ticks in dashboard2 than in dashboard1 is because of the different data sets (there is no css tricks in that). May be some expert can throw some light on **why more ticks**.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2mhvpKdDdyiP90Ch0c8H?p=preview) is a working plunk in which i have regulated the number of ticks

If you know what the tick values will be then use tickValues read [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickValues)

Comment: Ok that's a big step forward. Thank you again for helping me understand the ins and outs of D3. Now on purely aesthetic grounds, is it possible to get it more similar to the top graph? It seems the node offset or something needs to be adjusted. Do you know what I mean? When I look at your plunk, the grids are slightly different in size.

Comment: I forgot to mention the spacing is different too, I'm guessing size alone can't control the spacing 100%? Seems we might have to edit the margins or something? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah everything is different in both the graphs. One possible solution could be that if the scale extent(i.e. domain range) for both graphs be same...But what i see is that in both graphs the datasets are different, so I don't think you can have similar ticks for both graphs.

Comment: If anyone is still interested, I have some updates. When I specify different values for .ticks(), it sometimes has no effect. For example, when I try .ticks(5) and .ticks(8), they look exactly the same. At least using .ticks() got me closer to what I want, but it seems I cannot control the size using .ticks() alone. Is there anything else that d3.js will 'listen to' ?

Comment: ticks(5) gives a hint of how many ticks it will have. see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818565/what-does-it-take-for-ticks-to-work