# d3 .ticks() .tickValues() not updating in chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have seen others with this question ([What does it take for .ticks() to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818565/what-does-it-take-for-ticks-to-work)) but I still have not found a clear solution. My dataset is quite large and the x-axis tick labels (simple strings) are overlapping. I would like to set a maximum of maybe 10 ticks on the chart. A snippet of my code is below.

```
    // Add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (chart_height - margin["bottom"]) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(5),
    )
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", (y(d3.extent(y_values)[0]) - y(0) + 30))
    .style("font-family", "PT Sans")
    .style("font-size", "14px");
```

I am referencing this: https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_ticks but no matter what I do, my number of ticks never changes. I tried both .ticks() and .tickValues().

Am I maybe adding .ticks() to wrong portion of code? I'm super new to d3.

Comment: Could you please provide jsfiddle  or something similar?

Comment: Added! Hope it helps

Comment: People usually expect a JSFiddle to be executable rather than being a code dump. Please have a look at [ask] and how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: sorry about that, still new to all this. will try to fix JFiddle! thanks.

Comment: As I understand you need to reduce ticks number to avoid overlapping, did you tried to rotate ticks labels ? this can be an option to solve your issue, https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4403522

Comment: Any reason for the comma after the `.ticks(5)`? Also, which version of d3.js are you using?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your insights - I fixed this problem by making a separate array of every 5th label and filled the rest with empty strings. This way I had an array of the same length as the original array of labels but that rendered in a less cluttered format.