# How specify tickValues in d3.js time scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 and in my chart I have a scale that is a time scale in UTC format.

```
xScale  = d3.time.scale.utc().range([0,  chartWidth]);
```

I need to specify the ticks dynamically and change the domain dynamically to avoid clutter in the tick label.

I was calculating ticks based on the domain and setting the ticks to its closest multiple of 5. However, I noticed a problem where sometimes the tick positions were not consistent while changing the the domain. See image below:

[image]

Looking in some forum, I saw that it is possible to set the tick values by the function `tickValues(d3.range(starting value, end value, interval))`. [See this post by mbostock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100314/change-the-ticks-on-x-axis).

Now I am not sure--how can I do the same for my time scale?
If I want to calculate my own tick values for my xAxis (which uses a time scale in UTC) how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to force ticks of every N minutes? or N [time units]?

You can use:

```
var startDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0),
    endDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0),
    millisecondsBetweenTicks = 300000; //<-- 5 minutes

var x = d3.time.scale.utc()
    .domain([startDate, endDate])
    .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickValues(d3.range(startDate, endDate, millisecondsBetweenTicks )
                  .map(function(d){ return new Date(d) }) //<-- remap to dates
    );
```

---

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 250, right: 40, bottom: 250, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    startDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0),
    endDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0);

var x = d3.time.scale.utc()
    .domain([startDate, endDate])
    .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickValues(d3.range(startDate, endDate, 300000)
                  .map(function(d){ return new Date(d) })
    );

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");

</script>
```