# javascript d3 ticks format

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using d3.v4 and went though this tutorial for modifying number of ticks and the tick format 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9764126

however this works

```
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(11, '.0s') )
```

but when I do

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(11).tickFormat(d3.format('.0s')) )
```

[image: format is right but too many ticks]
The tick format seems to overwrite the number of ticks as the format is correct but there are too many ticks. I can get the ticks itself working by using

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(11) )
```

The tick format method is valid for d3v4, so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@echo - I would use `.tickValues()` along with `d3.range()` for this instead of `.ticks()`. As `.tickValues()` gives more control compared to `.ticks()`.

Here is your modified code:

```
 <script>
  const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",600).attr("height",500);
  const g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,500)");
  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([100000,1000000]).range([0,500]);
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.format('.0s')).tickValues(d3.range(100000,1000000,400000));
  g.call(xAxis).attr("transform","translate(10,200)");
</script>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/435j26sf/14/

Also, check this SO question on .tickValues()  [Change the ticks on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100314/change-the-ticks-on-x-axis).

Hope this helps.